# Rails- How to redirect to different pages when I have a user form on multiple pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to get a user to follow a specific path when they sign up (sign up, questionnaire page, dashboard), but I'm running into problems trying to get the questionnaire page to mind its own business.

Relevant bits of the controller:

```
def update
@user = current_user

 if @user.save
  redirect_to :back
  flash[:notice] = "Updated!"
 else
  redirect_to :back
  flash[:notice] = "Couldn't save your info"
 end
end


def questionnaire
@user = current_user

 if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])  # just informed this bit of code won't do anything
  redirect_to user_dashboard_path
  flash[:notice] = "Thanks for filling out the questionnaire."
 else
  redirect_to user_introduction_path
  flash[:notice] = "Couldn't save."
 end
end
```

Here's the view I'm using on the questionnaire page:

```
=simple_form_for @user, :url => {:action => "about_yourself"} do |f|
  %p What\'s your name?
  =f.input :name, label: "Your name, please."
  %p Gender?
  =simple_fields_for :personal_detail do |p|
    = p.input :gender, :collection => %w[Male Female]
  %p Age?
  =f.input :age
  =f.submit "Let's rock"
```

How do I get the form to redirect to a specific page when the form in a specific view updates the model? Basically use the update method from a different page with a different redirect if I need to.

Comment: just a thought, but just so you're clear, when you submit the form to update a user, it's going to go to the `update` action. you're not really accomplishing anything with the `if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])` in your `questionnaire` action.

Comment: Well, I think that's my issue... I'll rephrase my question, thanks!

Comment: I think you can add a hidden input within each specific view, and make those views to update to one controller then make condition for the hidden value to handle the redirect purpose.